# Setting appearance for multiple states - is there a way to do this in fewer lines?

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundImage:pressedButtonBackground30 forState:UIControlStateNormal style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundImage:pressedButtonBackground24 forState:UIControlStateNormal style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered barMetrics:UIBarMetricsLandscapePhone];
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundImage:pressedButtonBackground30 forState:UIControlStateHighlighted style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundImage:pressedButtonBackground24 forState:UIControlStateHighlighted style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone barMetrics:UIBarMetricsLandscapePhone];
```

In one post I saw, someone had `UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered|UIBarButtonItemStyleDone` as the `style` value but it won't work. Do I have to have the separate lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my view: who cares? You only have to do this once, at launch, and the `appearance` proxy idea is so much better than having to do this for every individual bar button item, which is how it *used* to be. Don't worry, be happy, move on.